# how can i add diamond or ellipse on jsplumb flowchart?

Tags: jsplumb

in the jsplumb toolkit plugins has a [flowchart](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/flowchart/index.html) generated plugin.
 
[image]flowchart generated by rectangular, but i need diamond or ellipse on the flowchart such as a lot of ordinary flowcharts.
how can i add diamond or ellipse on [this](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/flowchart/index.html) project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is not clear where you need diamonds... instead of anchors? or instead of nodes?
If you want diamonds anchors, jsPlumb supports them. Just set `shape: "Diamond"` property when you add an endpoint.

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint("someElement", {
  endpoint:"Dot",
  anchor:[ "Perimeter", { shape:"Diamond" } ]
});
```

See [jsPlumb help](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/anchors.html) for more info.

If you need diamond nodes you have to create a corresponding HTML-element. It's your responsibility, not jsPlumb. You can use [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) for that.